# MySQL select all days in date range even if no data is available for day

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have entries for each days as a punch in/out clock. I would like to display all days for the date givens week and show the days even if no data in found for that day.

Example:

```
Monday 2015-05-04
- 2015-05-04 10:30:00
- 2015-05-04 15:45:34

Tuesday 2015-05-05
- 2015-05-05 08:43:23
- 2015-05-05 17:18:13

Wednesday 2015-05-06
- 2015-05-06 09:03:12

Thursday 2015-05-07
0 Entries

Friday 2015-05-08
0 Entries
```

The DB schema looks like:

```
id | user_id | punch_time | punch_status
```

I would ideally like to be able to change the date given to MySQL to any timestamp and it would show the days and results for that week.

Thanks :D

---

**NEW**
Any ideas why this doesn't work to get days when no records are present?

```
SELECT * FROM punch_clock, calendar_table WHERE calendar_table.dt = DATE(punch_clock.punch_time) && calendar_table.week_num = $week && calendar_table.y = $year ORDER BY punch_clock.punch_time
```

**Newer Query**

```
 SELECT * FROM punch_clock LEFT JOIN calendar_table ON calendar_table.dt = DATE(punch_clock.punch_time) WHERE calendar_table.week_num = 18 && calendar_table.y = 2015;
```

Comment: What is the table structure? What have you tried?

Comment: Try grabbing all the data in the range you need and sort it by the date. then loop thorugh it with php

Comment: @sgtBOSE Updated with the schema

Comment: And what query have you tried.?

Comment: you'll need a calendar table to join against, to get values for all days

Comment: check this article on [creating calendar dimension in mysql](https://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables)

Comment: Counter suggestion: Just handle the logic of the missing results in your application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MySQL, I usually use a calendar table for this purpose (containing all the dates until 2030 for example)
It allows to do many other things like this kind of queries, manage special days, etc..

You'll want to `LEFT JOIN` your table on it, I mean this calendar table have to be "left positioned"

Taking your last query, I'd do this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM calendar AS cal
LEFT JOIN punch_clock AS puc
  ON (cal.dt = DATE(puc.punch_time))
WHERE TRUE
  AND cal.week_num = 18
  AND cal.y = 2015
;
```

Didn't try, but this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try of this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT a.Date AS mydate
    FROM (
           SELECT date('2015-05-08') - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY AS Date
           FROM (SELECT 0 AS a
                 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                 UNION ALL SELECT 2
                 UNION ALL SELECT 3
                 UNION ALL SELECT 4
                 UNION ALL SELECT 5
                 UNION ALL SELECT 6
                 UNION ALL SELECT 7
                 UNION ALL SELECT 8
                 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1
                         UNION ALL SELECT 2
                         UNION ALL SELECT 3
                         UNION ALL SELECT 4
                         UNION ALL SELECT 5
                         UNION ALL SELECT 6
                         UNION ALL SELECT 7
                         UNION ALL SELECT 8
                         UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1
                         UNION ALL SELECT 2
                         UNION ALL SELECT 3
                         UNION ALL SELECT 4
                         UNION ALL SELECT 5
                         UNION ALL SELECT 6
                         UNION ALL SELECT 7
                         UNION ALL SELECT 8
                         UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
         ) a
    WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '2015-05-04' AND '2015-05-08'
  ) dates
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM
      table1
  ) data
    ON DATE_FORMAT(dates.mydate, '%Y%m%d') = DATE_FORMAT(data.punch_time, '%Y%m%d')
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ee3/15/0

This is a fast but not that ideal solution for your question. But I think it's just enough for use.

If you'd like to solve the problem "perfectly", I suggest you reading this article: http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have read the article and implemented the calendar table. Would my next step be include both the punch_clock and calendar_table in a mysql query joining the date?

Comment: @tutchmedia It should be so. You can replace the `dates` in my SQL with your calendar.

Comment: Works awesome apart from it isn't showing the days that don't have data? (See my query in original post) any ideas?

Comment: need to left join from your calender table to your punchcard table

Comment: I can't seem to get this bit right. It still doesn't show the days with no entries (See newer query) - Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Even while this is a really old question I did not like the idea of an extra calendar table and came up with this query, adjusted for the question.

```
SELECT pc.`id`, pc.`user_id`, pc.`punch_status`, dates.`date` FROM punch_clock pc RIGHT JOIN (SELECT week.`date` FROM (
    SELECT CURDATE() AS `date`
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 DAY
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 DAY
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL 5 DAY
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL 6 DAY
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
       UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
    ) AS week 
WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 0) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 0)) AS dates ON dates.`date` = DATE(pc.`punch_time`) ORDER BY dates.`date`
```

Not exactly pretty, but it does the job without an extra table. This uses a week from Monday to Sunday, use `YEARWEEK(xxx, 1)` for Sunday to Monday week.